# How to realize 3D Curve Wall with jQuery or js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, assets

the effect i want to realize is just u can see from website below:
http://www.designasaurus.co.uk/page2/page9/page9.html

i do really want to realize this effect mainly using jQuery/js combined with html and css. And  the i'll put these resources under the `assets` of my Android project, so i can view this effect on my Android devices. Hoping some one can give me some tips or referenceing websites to realize it, or u can just tell me that: hey, buddy! u cann't realize it in you Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: No luck in Android Browser. Before WebGL, however, I would look into canvas Transform methods:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations

Start at "A Scale Example"

These should be less bleeding edge than WebGL

/Edit

To be honest, I'm a little behind on the latest CSS3 stuff but it sounds like CSS transforms would fit the bill.

I imagine android default browsers are pretty much Chrome. Looks like you could find some leads on how to do it with CSS here. See the bottom-most example.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/

Not sure how smooth that would go with a background image though.

For more complete control, you'd probably want to look into webGL which is still pretty bleeding edge but no more so than the latest CSS3 but the CSS3 might be all you need here.

Comment: actually,i'v found that Android default browser(or webview) do not support `CSS3 transforms` on version 2.2 or 2.3

Comment: I might have to edit then. This might be do-able in Canvas without webGL.

Comment: yeah! Android do not support webGL,either do it support CSS 3D Transform. I do have an idea that i can realize `3D Curve Wall` with `Canvas` and `camera`, however just i have the idea, i do not have the a clue to star it.

Comment: Check my edit. I'd be surprised if it didn't at least handle basic canvas transform.

Comment: hum, there's no problem with supporting or handleing the basic canvas transform. btw, the basic canvas's function can be replaced by a jQuery/js plugin. Maybe i just misunderstand your meaning. I just  emphasize that canvas's 2d transform may just can not meet i required.